# Stalks of the sheaf of total quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a scheme, for each $U$ open in $X$, let $S(U)$ be the set consisting of elements of $O_X(U)$ whose image in $O_{X,p}$ is a non-zerodivisor for every $p\in U$. In particular, if $U = \operatorname{Spec} A$, one can check that $S(U)$ consists of the set of all nonzerodivisors of $A$. Since $S(U)$ is multiplicative, we define a presheaf of rings $U \mapsto S(U)^{-1}O_X(U)$ with the obvious restriction map and its sheafification $\mathscr{K}_X$, which is called the *sheaf of total quotient rings* of $X$.

Let $A$ be any ring and denote by $K(A)$ its total quotient ring. I am suspecting that $\mathscr{K}_{X,p} = K(O_{X,p})$. Since sheafification preserves germs, it boils down to checking that
$$\mathscr{K}_{X,p} = \varinjlim_{p\in D(f)} K(A_f) \stackrel{?}{=} K(A_p).$$

My idea is the following: Since we have a system of compatible arrows $A\hookrightarrow K(A)$ and $A_f\hookrightarrow K(A_f)$, we have a natural map $A_p\to \mathscr{K}_{X,p}$. Since all nonzerodivisors of $A_p$ are invertible in the target, it factors to a morphism $\varphi: K(A_p)\to \mathscr{K}_{X,p}$. Conversely we have a system of compatible arrows $K(A)\to K(A_p)$ and $K(A_f)\to K(A_p)$, therefore it induces a morphism $\psi:\mathscr{K}_{X,p}\to K(A_p)$. And these two give the isomorphism. Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be false.  See the paper [Misconceptions about $K_X$](https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001%3A1979%3A25%3A%3A101) by Steven Kleiman.

Answer (score 1):

A partial result can be found in the [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02OW). Freely quoted:

> For any reduced scheme $X$ for which every quasi compact open contains finitely many irreducible components, the stalks of the sheaf of total quotient rings (meromorphic functions) at $x\in X$ are the total quotient rings of the stalk at $x$ of the structure sheaf of the scheme: $\mathcal{K}_{X,x}=\mbox{Q}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$.
>   Moreover, for such schemes a similar result holds on affine open patches $U\subseteq X$, namely: $\mathcal{K}_{X}(U)=\mbox{Q}(\mathcal{O}_X(U))$.